# java.lang.ArrayStoreException storing Integer in Integer array

Tags: java, arrays

Why am I getting this exception?

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.Integer
at MyLinkedList.toArray(MyLinkedList.java:94)
at MyLinkedListTest.toArray_ReturnGenericArray(MyLinkedListTest.java:80)
```

I am creating an Integer array and passing in Integer values. Why then, when I create a new instance of the same type of array, am I unable to assign integer values to it?

```
@Override
public <T1> T1[] toArray(T1[] a) {
    if (a.length < size) {
        a = (T1[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(a.getClass(), size);
    }
    Node<T> current = head;
    int i = 0;
    Object[] result = a;
    while (current != null) {
        result[i] = current.value;
        i++;
        current = current.next;
    }
    // if array has room to spare set element immediately following end of list to null
    if (a.length > i) {
        a[i] = null;
    }
    return a;
}

@Test
void toArray_ReturnGenericArray() {
    Integer[] array2 = linkedList.toArray(new Integer[4]);
    assertEquals(1, array2[0]);
    assertEquals(2, array2[1]);
    assertEquals(3, array2[2]);
    assertEquals(4, array2[3]);
    assertEquals(5, array2[4]);
    assertEquals(5, array2.length);
}
```

Comment: Use `java.util.Arrays#copyOf(U[], int, java.lang.Class<? extends T[]>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is this bit of code

```
a.getClass()
```

What it will return is not the class of the *component* of the array, but the array itself, e.g.

```
[Ljava.lang.Integer
```

See the `[L` prefix. You need to use

```
a.getClass().getComponentType()
```

As `Array#newInstance` accepts the component type

```
newInstance(Class<?> componentType, int length)
```